# DPDK flow filter get invalid action error

Tags: dpdk

I tried to change the example: flow_classify to use queue action.

The change is just:

```
//add:  
struct rte_flow_action_queue queue = { .index = 1 }; //enqueue to queue index: 1

//change count action to queue action. 
    //actions[0] = count_action;
    actions[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE;
    actions[0].conf = &queue;
```

After the change, when validate the rule, I get this error: table entry validate failed ipv4_proto = 17, Invalid action.

Thanks for any advice!

More info:
DPDK version: 19.11.2, bind using igb_uio

NIC card: driver: ixgbe

version: 4.4.0-k-rh7.3

firmware-version: 0x80000922,

expansion-rom-version: bus-info: 0000:01:00.1, supports-statistics: yes, supports-test: yes, supports-eeprom-access: yes, supports-register-dump: yes, supports-priv-flags: no

Device configuration:

```
rx_rings: 2, tx_rings: 1, 
struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = port_conf_default;
struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
retval = rte_eth_dev_info_get(port, &dev_info);
if (retval != 0)
    return retval;
if (dev_info.tx_offload_capa & DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE)
    port_conf.txmode.offloads |= DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE;
retval = rte_eth_dev_configure(port, rx_rings, tx_rings, &port_conf);
if (retval != 0)
    return retval;
retval = rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc(port, &nb_rxd, &nb_txd);
```

Comment: DPDK rte_flow is hevaily influenced by DPDK version, NIC, firmware. So please update the question with all the details. Also please add code snippet of dev_configure too,

Comment: thanks for the information, there are a couple of things to try out 1) update the firmware http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_19_11.html, 2) On NIC HW like Fortville IP proto field should not be applied if one uses TCP|UDP|SCTp. Hence can you try setting `ipv4_spec.hdr.next_proto_id = 0;` or setting `ipv4_spec.hdr.next_proto_id = 0;`

Comment: can you share your update?

Comment: built19.11.7. then bind new igb_uio.ko (but looks same as 11.9.2). also build codes using 19.11.7, same error: table entry validate failed ipv4_proto = 17, Invalid action. I set: ipv4_spec.hdr.next_proto_id = 0, and compile with 19.11.7, get error: EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1, Cause: add rule error. Found inside add_classify_rule function, switch ipv4_proto, if not TCP, UDP or STCP, it returns error. Tried to remove UDP, only left IP, by pattern_ipv4_5tuple[1] = ipv4_udp_item; pattern_ipv4_5tuple[2] = end_item; then get: table entry validate failed ipv4_proto = 17, Unsupported pattern

Comment: if your NIC is `Intel® 82599ES` firmware should be `0x61bf0001` please use http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_19_11.html to narrow down the correct firmware. Thanks for trying out the suggestion, as I understand the original flow _Calssify itself is not working for you. I recommend start with simple rte_flow example and ensure your nic is capable of handling the same. Please let me know if you need help in testing the same (as I do not have 10Gbps ixgbe nic) to try out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Firmware version is likely because I use centos7.3. For rte_flow example, action is Count, it works.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT based on the comment update] Possible cause of specific action to fail is most likely the firmware of NIC does not match with DPDK specific requirement.

As per [DPDK 19.11 release notes](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_19_11.html) expected firmware is `0x61bf0001`. Since it does not match with the current version, the recommendation is to use the suggested firmware

Note: as per comment action `count` works.

[EDIT-1] based on the live debug we were able to make RTE_FLOW with action `QUEUE redirect` work. Analysing DPDK example `flow_classify` INTEL NIC 82599 with ixgbe does not allow IP_PROTO field as part of rule.

Hence RTE_FLOW with Action QUEUE works on the NIC with right firmware

Comment: I do a NIC firmware driver upgrade: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/41282/Intel-82599ES-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Controller, upgrade to latest version 5.11.3. From ethtool -i, the firmware version is 0x80000922. I don't understand how to get 0x61bf0001. by the way, is related to http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html ? which driver should I bind to?

Comment: looks liek your firmware upgrade has resulted into `0x80000922`. Did you try running the application? are you not binding with `igb_uio` for running DPDK application?

Comment: i try to bind to igb_uio or uio_pci_generic, and run the application. still same issue: invalid action error, when call: rte_flow_classify_validate. by the way ethtool -i to get firmware version is before binding to igb_uio, after binding to igb_uio, ethtool -i cannot be used. But application run after binding to igb_uio.

Comment: what is your NIC? please execute `lshw -c net -businfo`.

Comment: Bus info          Device         Class          Description
===========================================================
pci@0000:01:00.0  enp1s0f0       network        82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:01:00.1  enp1s0f1       network        82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:03:00.0  eno1           network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:03:00.1  eno2           network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection

Comment: @zigzag but in the above comment, you have stated after the firmware upgrade resulted in `0x80000922`. But the official supported firmware is `0x61bf0001` as per Intel download and DPDK.  Something is really wrong, I can offer debug in skype, zoom, google meet.

Comment: ok. that is wonderful. can we do it on Monday?  (21 Jun 2021) what time are you available? google meet?

Comment: I am based out of India, I can make it for 8:00 AM IST

Comment: Sure. We share the google link around the time.

Comment: After checking the codes inside: igb_flow.c, after change action from count to queue, ixgbe_parse_ntuple_filter will failed, as IP address mask for ntuple can only be 0 or MAX. For the pattern match will only be: ixgbe_parse_rss_filter. But rss_filter only allow RSS action.